# foodcritic (3.0.3) gem installation is failing in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: ruby, rubygems, yajl

My food critic gem installation is failing with the below error

```
Following gems were not installed:
foodcritic (3.0.3): Error installing foodcritic
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. current directory
/Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl
/Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf/20180729-63637-1dtcegj.rb.extconf.rb creating Makefile current
directory: /Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl make "DESTDIR=" clean current
directory: /Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl make "DESTDIR=" compiling
yajl.c compiling yajl_alloc.c compiling yajl_buf.c compiling yajl_encode.c compiling yajl_ext.c yajl_ext.c:852:22 error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum' rb_define_method(rb_cFixnum, "to_json", rb_yajl_json_ext_fixnum_to_json, -1); ^ 1 error generated.

make: *** [yajl_ext.o] Error 1 make failed, exit code 2 Gem files remain installed in 
/Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0 for inspection. Results logged to
/Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.5.0-static/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/gem_make.out
```

Output of `gem_make.out`

```
current directory: /Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl
/Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180729-63637-1dtcegj.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/dmanna/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl
make "DESTDIR="
compiling yajl.c
compiling yajl_alloc.c
compiling yajl_buf.c
compiling yajl_encode.c
compiling yajl_ext.c
yajl_ext.c:852:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    rb_define_method(rb_cFixnum, "to_json", rb_yajl_json_ext_fixnum_to_json, -1);
                     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [yajl_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

- rbenv version - 2.5.1 OS
- Mac 10.13.6

I am new to ruby. I am getting this error when trying to import a project in RubyMine and installing the gems.

Can someone let me know what is going wrong and how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foodcritic 3.0.3 is from 2013. See here:
https://rubygems.org/gems/foodcritic/versions/3.0.3

Unfortunately it is not compatible with the latest version of Ruby. Your choices are to either downgrade Ruby to something less than 2.4, maybe even as low as 1.9 to be sure of compatibility, or upgrade foodcritic to its latest version (14.0.0).